# Mapping mutable methods onto Java objects in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, interop

Using Clojure, suppose `t` represents a Java object, and I have a collection of `[ts]`.

How can I map `.setter` to `[ts]`? I'm having trouble using `(map #(.setter %1 %2) ts [vals])`. When I access the associated getters afterwards, I return a list of `nil`s.

Comment: You might also like `clojure.core/memfn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an example of `ArrayList` Java class. I create three of those, and then I add "s1" to the first one, "s2" to the second and "s3" to the third. This is my "setter".

Then I read the first value of each, and I expect to get "s1", "s2", "s3" - so that's a getter in this example.

```
(let [ts [(java.util.ArrayList. 1)
          (java.util.ArrayList. 1)
          (java.util.ArrayList. 1)]]
  ; Add one element to each of the ArrayList's
  (doall (map #(.add %1 %2) ts ["s1" "s2" "s3"]))

  ; Verify that elements are indeed added.
  (doall (map #(.get %1 0) ts)))
```

This example works as expected - the latter `mapv` returns `("s1" "s2" "s3")`.

**Why the similar approach would not work for you? Well, my strong suspiction is that's because you use [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) which returns a lazy sequence.**

`map` returns a lazy sequence, which means that it will not evaluate unless you try to get/use the values produced by it - and you usually don't need a return value from a setter. This means that your setter would be never called.

That's why I've used [`doall`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall) - it will take a lazy sequence and realize it, meaning that each element will get computed (in your case - each setter will get called).

My example, when I use only `map` and not `doall` when setting elements, would fail:

```
(let [ts [(java.util.ArrayList. 1)
          (java.util.ArrayList. 1)
          (java.util.ArrayList. 1)]]
  ; Use a lazy map here - without doall
  (map #(.add %1 %2) ts ["s1" "s2" "s3"])
  (doall (map #(.get %1 0) ts)))

; java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

It fails indeed, because no element got added.

Alternatively, you can use a [`mapv`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapv) variant that returns a vector and hence is always not lazy:

```
(let [ts [(java.util.ArrayList. 1)
          (java.util.ArrayList. 1)
          (java.util.ArrayList. 1)]]
  ; Use a lazy map, but realize sequence using doall
  (doall (map #(.add %1 %2) ts ["s1" "s2" "s3"]))
  (mapv #(.get %1 0) ts))
```

As pointed out by @John Wiseman in the comment, though, `mapv` is probably a worse choice because it's not always clear that it's used to force realization, while `doall` makes it clear and obvious.

---

A word about lazy sequences:

```
A lazy seq is a seq whose members aren't computed until you try to access them.
```

[(source)](http://www.braveclojure.com/core-functions-in-depth/#2_3__Lazy_Seqs)

It's a good thing to learn more about lazy seqs, as they're a powerful tool used all over in Clojure codebases. One somewhat counter-intuitive thing they bring to the table is an ability to create infinite sequences, i.e. (range) creates an infinite sequence of all numbers starting with 0. So it's perfectly legal to do:

```
(map #(* % %) (range))
```

It will create an infinite lazy sequence of squares of all the numbers!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `mapv` just to avoid laziness--it obscures the programmer's intention. `doall` has the one purpose, and if I see `doall` in code I know precisely why it's there.

Comment: @JohnWiseman - good point, I'll rearrange the answer to make it the default choice.

Comment: In this case I'd use `doseq` instead of `doall`. Given that OP is mutating the collection in-place, there is no need to generate another intermediate collection that gets discarded.

Comment: I thought `doseq` at first, but there's the collection of `vals` and I wasn't sure how to best handle them.  `(doseq [[t v] (map vector ts vals)] (.setter t v))` seems kinda pointless.

Comment: `dorun` is preferable to `doall` if you are not accessing the return value of the operation. And in Clojure 1.7 you can use `run!` instead of `(dorun (map ...))` (except in this case, because sadly unlike map `run!` does not take an arbitrary args list)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the `setter` method isn't returning the modified `t` object.  If you wrote `setter`, you could modify it so that it does, or you will just have to hold on to your original `ts` (but also make sure to use [`dorun`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doall) to squeeze out the laziness of `map`):

```
(let [ts ...]
  (dorun (map #(.setter %1 %2) ts [vals]))
  (println "Modified ts:" ts))
```

An alternative, if it would be much more convenient for you to have the `map` return the collection, is to do something like this:

```
(dorun (map #(do (.setter %1 %2) %1) ts [vals]))
```

Comment: I changed `doall` to `dorun` based on @noisesmith's comment on another answer.